# Parse Particular Date Format C#

Tags: c#, datetime-format

Can anybody help me convert this into date time format?

> 20210115122710

I need in format like

```
  DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("20210115122710", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are parsing `DateTime` with wrong format, use `"yyyyMMddHHmmss"` instead of `"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"`,

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("20210115122710", "yyyyMMddHHmmss", null);
```

Now whenever you want to print it in given format, then use `.ToString()` method,

```
string dateInGivenFormat = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

---

**Note:** I used `HH` for hours instead of `hh`.

- `HH` : Use of `HH` converts hours in **24-hours** format i.e from 00 to 23.
- `hh` : `hh` converts hours in **12-hours** format i.e from 00 to 12.

If your time is in 12-hour format then use `hh` otherwise use `HH`.

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cz7zV2)

Comment: I suspect it should be `HH` rather than `hh`.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I fixed it to use `HH` instead of `hh` for hours.